# How do I create an attribute dynamically while using yattag?

Tags: html, json, yattag

This is the part of 'data' in the code below:

```
{'element': 'background', 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'width': 800, 'height': 898, 'properties': {'background-color': '#ffffff'}}
```

The code:

```
for i in data:
    print(i)
    if i['element'] in comp:
        ta = i['element']
        if i['properties']:
            prop_keys = list(i['properties'].keys())
            background = "green"
            for j in range(len(prop_keys)):
                attri = prop_keys[j]
                print(type(attri))
                val = i['properties'][prop_keys[j]]
                print(type(val))
                doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
                exec('with tag(ta, %s = %s)'%(attri,val))
    break
```

The error that I am getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/harsh/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-78-69185a93c0dd>", line 19, in <module>
    exec('with tag(ta, %s = %s)'%(attri,val))

  File "<string>", line 1
    with tag(ta, background-color = #ffffff)
                                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I basically want to use value of 'attri' as the name of attribute in the yattag to make it dynamic.
I tried using 'exec' function to put in the values to convert the json data into html using yattag but the yattag library doesn't allow to use expression in place of variable name to make it dynamic.

Comment: You can do: `with tag('ta', **properties)`

Comment: No need for `exec`

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional this did'nt work. Also `ta` is not a string, and I need to use 'with tag(ta, attri = val)` where `attri` is a variable which gets replaced by its value `prop_keys[j]` and still remain a variable.

Comment: "For any other situation where an attribute's name can't be expressed as a Python identifier, you can use (key, value) pairs." cf https://www.yattag.org/#the-tag-method

Comment: Use `with tag(ta, *properties.items())` (I deleted a previous comment similar to this one where I had omitted the  star `*`, that's probably why it didn't work for you). The star symbol `*` unpacks the (key, value) pairs to pass them to the function.